# Isekai manga where a girl is teleported to earth in the countryside of Japan, taken by the government, and tested for the disease

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's an isekai manga where a girl is teleported to earth in the countryside of Japan, starts living with the MC, is then taken by the government, and is tested for diseases. And then the girl and MC return back together to home, and start living their everyday life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Regarding That We Decided to Live in the Countryside With The Female Knight Who Came to Us***

I believe this is *[俺んちに来た女騎士と 田舎暮らしすることになった件](https://myanimelist.net/manga/115041/Orenchi_ni_Kita_Onna_Kishi_to_Inakagurashi_suru_Koto_ni_Natta_Ken)*, (in romaji *Orenchi ni Kita Onna Kishi to Inakagurashi suru Koto ni Natta Ken*) also known as *Regarding That We Decided to Live in the Countryside With The Female Knight Who Came to Us*. It is the adaptation of a [web novel](https://anilist.co/manga/105581/Orenchi-ni-Kita-Onna-Kishi-to-Inakagurashi-Surukotoninatta-Ken/) of the same name.

The main characters are a farmer in a rural area, and a lady knight who came from another world. The farmer lets her live with him after he found her. At one point, the government found out about the lady knight being from another world and quarantined them both in a facility. After a month or two, they were allowed to go back to their farm.

## Cover

[image: 俺んちに来た女騎士と 田舎暮らしすることになった件 manga cover]

### Web novel cover

[image: 俺んちに来た女騎士と 田舎暮らしすることになった件 novel cover]

Comment: Thanks a lot man